# Double Android SDK folder

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have seen that in my Android path C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android I have 2 SDK folders. I am wondering if this could give some issue to Android Studio and if I have to delete one of these folders.

It seems that SDK1 has more data than SDK but I don't want to make disaster by deleting the wrong one.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

open your android studio , `File`->`Project Structure`->`SDK Location` , Keep the sdk which android studio is using and delete other . Here is a screen shot , in my case location is `/home/redman/Android/Sdk`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please select only one folder for SDK. You should delete new one SDK Folder which is created at 01-02-18. Or select proper path when update your SDK.

1. Set SDK Path First from setting - SDK Manager

-Set Android SDK Location.
-Update require SDK.